# Karate -TestNG stop execution when any one of the step fail

Tags: karate

Karate step execution stops when any one of the step fails.

Example:
Scenario : verify user details.

Given url "this is my webservice"

When method post

Then status 200

*assert 1==2

Then response

Then match XXXXXXX

The match XXXX

The steps fails  Assert , remain steps does not execute. Is there any way even my assert fails remaining steps can continue the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

But you can use the [`karate.match()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-match) function to perform the assert manually. Then you can use [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic) to decide if you want to continue next steps or not. But I [totally don't recommend](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html) this.

For example:

```
* def temp = karate.match(actual, expected)
* print 'some step'
* assert temp.pass
```