# Always execute final steps

Tags: testing, karate

I saw [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796262/karate-testng-stop-execution-when-any-one-of-the-step-fail) where [Rama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10061962/rama) asked something super related. But the response he got was that doing what he wanted was posible but super not recomendable.

So, having that in mind, I wanted to know how this kind of scenario would be solved using Karate Framework:

1. Some data is created and saved in a data base.
2. Some API's are called and some asserts are evaluated.
3. The information created above should be removed to leave the data
   base as it was before.

Since the execution is going to stop in the asserts if they fail... how would be the way to have the data that was created cleaned from the data base in case of failure?

Thanks in advance!